# “Life that means you” or “life that mean for you”?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction

> A life that means you.

> A life that mean for you.

Are both sentences constructed correctly?

I want to indicate a life that means you and reflects you or the way you want your life to be.

Comment: It seems like you want to talk about the *meaning of life* or your *purpose in life* or your *life's purpose*.

Comment: Yes I want to talk about that.. exactly.. you get me right..

Comment: "A life that means you, reflect you, or the way you want it to be" is not a complete sentence, so it is difficult to suggest the best wording for you. Can you give a complete sentence? For example: "It is important for everybody to have [a life that means you]..." Is that the kind of sentence you want to write?

Comment: Plausible sentences I can think of are: **"What is life for you?"**, **"This is your life's purpose."**, **A life that reflects who you are"** and **"Live your life the way you want to live it"**

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you are talking about a life lived such that it demonstrates the special, intangible qualities that are unique to a particular individual. I recommend:

> *. . . a life that **expresses who you are.***

If instead you wish to refer to a life lived with a fulfilling sense of purpose, I recommend:

> *. . . a life that **is meaningful to you.***